# CommentThread.list with "?" searchTerm returning empty set

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As the title states, I can't get any way to filter all CommentThreads using the "?" searchTerm, this returns an empty list of CommentThreads.

Tried \? , \?, plain %03F, unicode \u0003F. Nothing seems to work.
Is there a way to filter by the questionmark ? I'm trying to retrieve all the questions from a video and if I can't filter this way it means I have to pull down everything and filter locally, which is really expensive (quota-wise).

Here is the api explorer url :

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.list?part=id%252Csnippet&maxResults=10&order=time&searchTerms=%253F&textFormat=html&videoId=o4lMYiwKYRs&fields=items(replies%252Csnippet)%252CnextPageToken&_h=18&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or not, but it seems that the [`searchTerms`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#searchTerms) parameter has its own rules to make itself works or filter the results.

Let us use this `videoId=2ecT9zf1QZU` that has a comments of:

**24**

**kobe bryant?**

**24kobe**

**?kobe**

**kobe? bryant**

**IDOL24**

If we use [`searchTerms=?`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.list?part=snippet&maxResults=10&searchTerms=%253F&videoId=2ecT9zf1QZU&_h=24&), we will get **0 result** like the one you experienced, because I think it does not work with special character alone or words that have this special character. (**eg. ?**)

If we use [`searchTerms=kobe`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.list?part=snippet&maxResults=10&searchTerms=kobe&videoId=2ecT9zf1QZU&_h=23&), we will get **3 results**, (**kobe bryant?**, **?kobe** and **kobe? bryant**) so it work with a word without special character.

Now, we use [`searchTerms=?kobe and searchTerms=kobe?`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.list?part=snippet&maxResults=10&searchTerms=kobe%253F&videoId=2ecT9zf1QZU&_h=22&), we will get **0 result** because of the special character **?**.

What if we use [`searchTerms=yant`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.list?part=snippet&maxResults=10&searchTerms=yant&videoId=2ecT9zf1QZU&_h=21&) (from the word **bryant**), the result is **0**, because there is no word in the result that have a word **yant**.

So meaning there are some rules or limitation in using this **searhTerms**.

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: This helps actually.  I guess I'm going to pull down every single comment in order to filter them but it's a shame we can't just filter.

But I can understand why Google don't want to provide advanced filtering. They can spare the bandwidth, not the processing power :D